# mapreduce wordcount program in horton sandbox 2.1

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to execute mapreduce wordcount program in horton which works sandbox 2.1.

I got the following **Error**

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionErrorUnsupported major.minor version
52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    atjava.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClenter code hereass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

and in eclipse i got this eroor at the time of compling..

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.(Configuration.java:169)
>   at first.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:51) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ... 2 more ..

A detailed answer for my approach is highly appreciated.

Comment: Moved your comment with the error message into the text of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You error suggest that you're using a lower JVM version than the one the application was build. Try upgrading your java version

Comment: i have java 1.7 version insatlled in sanbox and in windows i have java 8...but i have set the compiler level in eclipse as 1.7...any more setting i ned to do now....